# C++ Win32 - How to loop MIDIs with mciSendString()?

Tags: c++, winapi, loops, midi, mci

I am making a game and I am trying to loop a MIDI file with mciSendString(). I have looked at CProgramming.com but the example's window objects were OWL and I couldn't port them. I also tried looking at Brian Gradin's question but the answer only contained two lines of code. I have looked on MSDN but that is like a reference and not a tutorial. Adding repeat doesn't play anything. This is the code that I have so far:

```
mciSendString("open PUG1.MID type sequencer alias music", NULL, 0, NULL);
mciSendString("play music", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

If you help then I will be sure to put you in the credits.
Thank you! :)

EDIT: I have tried to handle the notify flag but my code will not work. It plays the theme once then it stops.

```
    //At the end of WM_CREATE...
    mciSendString("open MUSIC\\PUG2.MID type sequencer alias music", NULL, 0, NULL);
    mciSendString("play music", NULL, 0, NULL);
break;
case MM_MCINOTIFY:
    mciSendString("seek music to start", NULL, 0, NULL);
    mciSendString("play music", NULL, 0, NULL);
break;
```

Comment: Have you tried `play music repeat`?

Comment: It doesn't play anything when you add it to a MIDI file.

Comment: Oh well, worth a try.  Seems like you will have to handle it manually as suggested in the question you mentioned.  The `notify` flag may be a better way to do so if it is supported with the sequencer.  You might also consider a 3rd party library.

Comment: I am sorry I am bothering you but could you please post an example. My code seems to be incorrect. I will edit the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `notify` flag be notified when the song ends.

This seems to work:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    mciSendString("open pickin0.mid type sequencer alias music", NULL, 0, NULL);
    mciSendString("play music notify", NULL, 0, hWnd);
    break;

case MM_MCINOTIFY:
    mciSendString("seek music to start", NULL, 0, NULL);
    mciSendString("play music notify", NULL, 0, hWnd);
    break;
```

You need to pass your window handle when you use the notify command so it can send the `MM_MCINOTIFY` command somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, Retired Ninja. I will be sure to add your name to the credits. :)